# Redundant conformance error message Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift

I updated my project to Swift 2, and received a bunch of `redundant conformance of XXX to protocol YYY`. This happens especially often (or always) when a class conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`. Also some place with `Equatable`.

```
class GraphFeatureNumbersetRange: GraphFeature, CustomStringConvertible { // <--- get the error here
...
}
```

I suspect that I don't need to explicitly conform to a protocol when I implement `var description: String { get }`, or whatever methods the protocol requires. Should I just follow fixit instructions and remove all these? Does Swift now automatically infer the conformance if a class implements all the protocol's methods?

Comment: *"I suspect that I don't need to explicitly conform to a protocol"*… this is incorrect. If you want to interact with a protocol, you must explicitly conform to it. *"Should I just follow fixit instructions?"* You need to add more detail to your question so we can reproduce the issue. *"Does Swift now automatically infer the conformance if a class implements all the protocol's methods?"* No.

Comment: @0x7fffffff `CustomStringConvertible ` is a new protocol in Swift 2 - [see here](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/protocol/CustomStringConvertible/). Not sure about `GraphFeature`.

Comment: @AaronBrager:  Not really new, just renamed from `Printable`.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You'll get that error message in Xcode 7 (Swift 2) if a subclass declares conformance
to a protocol which is already inherited from a superclass. Example:

```
class MyClass : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "MyClass" }
}

class Subclass : MyClass, CustomStringConvertible {
    override var description: String { return "Subclass" }
}
```

The error log shows:

```
main.swift:10:27: error: redundant conformance of 'Subclass' to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'
class Subclass : MyClass, CustomStringConvertible {
                          ^
main.swift:10:7: note: 'Subclass' inherits conformance to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible' from superclass here
class Subclass : MyClass, CustomStringConvertible {
      ^
```

Removing the protocol conformance from the subclass declaration
solves the problem:

```
class Subclass : MyClass {
    override var description: String { return "Subclass" }
}
```

But the superclass must declare the conformance explicitly, it is
not automatically inferred from the existence of the `description`
property.

Comment: In my instance I would love to use the override keyword, but Xcode freaks about overriding overloaded operators (== for Equatable). Any ideas?

Comment: it's not necessary to use the override keyword. See the section "Equivalence Operators" in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_43

Comment: @MaxMacLeod if not using the override keyword how do you ensure a custom implementation of == gets called? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085839/overridden-function-for-equatable-type-not-called-for-custom-class

Comment: So which class is it actually inheriting, I mean the class inheriting the `CustomDebugStringConvertible`

Answer (score 9):

For googlers, I also got this error when including SwiftyJson in my Tests target and adding a swift test class, as it caused SwiftyJson to be compiled in again, and it declares NSNumber as Comparable. The solution was to only include it in the app target.

Comment: It might happen that you can't set your file's target only for the current app (and not also the tests). If this happens, separate the file into two files, one that contains the redundant protocol conformance (make it current target only) and one that has the rest of the code (set its target to both your app and app tests).

Comment: This answer helped me realise I had the source file being tested added as a member of both my App and the Testing target. Removing it as a member of the testing target resolved the error. Strange though that the error appeared suddenly after this being the case for a long time. I'm not exactly sure what the trigger was, as I'd been running tests (very similar ones too) for ages on the prior ownership setup.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that your GraphFeatureNumbersetRange is **NSObject's** subclass.
Which in its turn **already** **conforms** to **CustomStringConvertible**! That's it! Just delete this redundant protocol. Now you're declaring it twice! :-)