# Redundant conformance of 'NSDate' to protocol 'Comparable' Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdate

Up until today my complete project was running fine. After closing and reopening Xcode I found an error with the following,

```
extension NSDate : Comparable {}
```

The error says, "Redundant conformance of 'NSDate' to protocol 'Comparable'"

The only recent additions to the project was a third party library called SwiftDate. If any other code is required, happy to post. Thank you.

Comment: Just comment out one of them

Comment: One of them? The 'NSDate : Comparable {}' is required for the application to function properly. @LeoDabus

Comment: If the conformance of NSDate to Comparable is already declared in the SwiftDate project then you must not declare it again. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867937/redundant-conformance-error-message-swift-2.

Comment: Thank you! One of the SwiftDate files contained the same declaration. How do I go about marking this question as answered? @MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftDate also had the same NSDate declaration as in my own project which caused the "Redundant conformance of NSDate" error.

(Thanks to Martin R for pointing that out)