# Overridden == function for Equatable type not called for custom class that subclasses NSCoding and NSObject

Tags: swift, nsobject, nscoding, equatable

The `FooBar` class below has to override the `==` function of the `Equatable` type.

However, calling `contains` on an array of `FooBar` objects does not cause a breakpoint inside the custom `==` function to get invoked. Is it possible another `==` function is overriding this custom one?

Note: Because FooBar must subclass from NSCoding and NSObject, FooBar does not list Equatable as a protocol because it causes this error:

> Redundant conformance of 'FooBar' to protocol 'Equatable'

```
func ==(lhs: FooBar, rhs: FooBar) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

class FooBar: NSObject, NSCoding {
     // Class def
}

// Both serverFooBars and gFooBars are [FooBar]
let newFooBars = serverFooBars.filter { !gFooBars.contains($0) }
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Because your class inherits from `NSObject` you do not need to use the swift protocol `Equatable` instead you must override the `NSObject` method `isEquals`:

**Swift 3.x and above**

```
class FooBar: NSObject, NSCoding {
  override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    return id == (object as? FooBar)?.id
  }
}
```

(Thanks to Kamchatka)

**Swift 2.x**

```
class FooBar: NSObject, NSCoding {
  override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return id == (object as? FooBar)?.id
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing so caused an error, hence its omission. The error: Redundant conformance of 'Recipe' to protocol 'Equatable'

Comment: @Crashalot is it required your class inherits from NSObject for any reason?

Comment: Isn't it needed for NSCoding?

Comment: look at the Equatable protocol, you must implement: `func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` (inside the class)

Comment: @Crashalot thats correct, the reason its saying its redundant because the class inherits from NSObject has the `isEquals` method.. though im going to check this out myself now

Comment: @DanielKrom, i mention that must be implemented in my answer but i will edit it to make it more clear

Comment: @DanielKrom inside the class generates an error; you're sure?

Comment: @BlakeLockley yes the question is how to override == if you must also subclass NSCoding?

Comment: @Crashalot yep http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/

Comment: @DanielKrom my bad i mis read your comment, no it must be implemented outside of the class because when you use the equatable function you are not within the scope of the class. e.g. fooBar == fooBar is not the same as calling a method on fooBar.

Comment: @Crashalot override isEquals - ill edit my answer

Comment: @BlakeLockley Hmm, The syntax is like global operator, but if you implement a protocol you have to implement the protocol functions inside the class that implements that, but I may be wrong

Comment: Cool will try and report back!

Comment: @DanielKrom thats true for all protocols with the exceptions being `Equatable` and `Comparable` or any other protocol that requires an overload implementation of an operator.

Comment: Works thanks so much! Would be ideal if you included the `self == (object as? FooBar) bit` from Odrakir's answer as this is even more explicit for Swift newbies.

Comment: @Crashalot no worries :) you could just include your implementation of `==` inside the `isEquals`  then theres no reason to downcast it and call `==`. But thats all down to preference.

Comment: How do you not downcast it?

Comment: @Crashalot i'll edit my answer

Comment: @Crashalot my mistake, you still need to perform a downcast for the other object but this way you dont need to worry about implementation of `==` .

Comment: Note: In Swift 3 the signature of this method is now: `override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {`

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because NSObject already conforms to Equatable through its isEqual method.

So I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, but you could override the isEqual method of NSObject:

```
class FooBar: NSObject, NSCoding {
...

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return self == (object as? FooBar)
}
```

Comment: That worked but unfortunately Blake was helping earlier and published his answer a bit sooner. Thanks though!

Comment: I see that now. He didn't show how to still use the == override, though... :)

Comment: @Crashalot ill share the love and upvote this one aswell, glad we all could help!

Comment: He updated the answer to show how to use the == override. It's true your answer is more explicit, but you can see how much time Blake spent beforehand and he gave the right answer -- just not the perfect answer like yours. Your answer was upvoted, though! :)

Comment: Can't see the part about overriding ==, but, ok, whatever...